# maven copy dependecies not working

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, classpath

This question ha sbeen asked but none of the solutions worked for me so:

I want to copy my jars which are specified through the dependency tags in the build of POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
...
</dependency>
```

into a folder like target/lib

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-jars</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/my-repo</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Swapper</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Like i said, nothing is copied at all. But according to some Q&A on this portal it should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What maven goals are you running? e.g. `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: i tried lots of combinations, mvn clean install, mvn package but none of them trigggred the copy process

Comment: Can you give a hint you are trying to accomplish ? Creating a installation/distribution package ?

Comment: I want to compile java code with some dependencies (other jars) to a jar or at least some .class files. The dependencies should be incuded in the classpath and reside in a lib folder next to the jar.

Comment: Just a note: One of Maven's basic concepts is _Convention over configuration_. Hence, declaring `<directory>` and `<finalName>` with values that are the defaults anyway is superfluous. See also [POM Reference, The BaseBuild Element Set](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are declaring your plugins in your `<pluginManagement>` section. This is all well and good, but if want them to *execute* you need to declare them outside the `<pluginManagement>` section:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
     ...
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Think of `<pluginManagement>` in the same way you think of `<dependencyManagement>`, but for plugins.

Comment: A wise man once said: "Think of <pluginManagement> in the same way you think of <dependencyManagement>, but for plugins."

Answer (score 1):

Add in goal like below based on your plugin

```
mvn clean install dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>Swapper</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By This :

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
            <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Swapper</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs> 
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Hi, strangely with this solution i get the missing main attribute manifest in jar error (tested with mvn install, mvn package)

Comment: in <mainClass>Swapper</mainClass> add you package mainClass>com.company.Swapper</mainClass>

Comment: Well, my main class is in the default folder from maven (src/main/java) default package